# How to change data php to javascript json

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have looping data:

```
image1
url1
description1

image2
url2
description2

image3
url3
description3

image4
url4
description4

image5
url5
description5
```

**Result:**

```
var imagesDataArray = [ 
   {
      src: 'images1',
      url: 'url1',
      description: 'description1'
   },
   {
      src: 'images2',
      url: 'url2',
      description: 'description2'
   },
   {
      src: 'images3',
      url: 'url3',
      description: 'description3',
   },
   {
      src: 'images4',
      url: 'url4',
      description: 'description4'
   },
   {
      src: 'images5',
      url: 'url5',
      description: 'description5'
   }
];
```

Comment: Do you want php array to json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to encode your PHP array to JSON. Use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for that.

```
json_encode($array);
```

> Returns a string containing the JSON representation of value.

Answer (score 0):

If backend is under your control instead of returning plain data use, **json_encode($data)**
and return json.
In JS All you have to load the response into a variable and manipulate it according to your needs.
Returning plain data from backend is unnecessary code complication inside javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your php file, it will return a string containing the JSON.

```
<?php
echo '<script>';
echo 'var $data = ' . json_encode($phpdata) . ';';
echo '</script>';
?>
```

Then use the variable $data for your code.